# Variance and covariance inequality

Tags: probability, variance, covariance, inequality

Given a real-valued random variable $X$, is

$$2\mathbb E[X] \mathrm{Var}(X) \geq \mathrm{Cov}(X, X^2)$$

true?

Any pointers for how to tackle this problem would be immensely helpful.

Comment: This reads as rather a textbook sort of problem. How does it arise? Please see our [help/on-topic] under homework for how we treat such questions (whether or not they are actually homework).

Comment: No, it's not a homework, nor is it a textbook problem. It comes about from a broader research question in which a part reduces to this. I have tried but failed to prove the above inequality. Any pointers to how to tackle this would be immensely helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the additional detail

Comment: For $X \sim \mathrm{Normal}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, both left and right hand sides are equal to $2\mu \sigma^2$ (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353957/covariance-of-a-normal-with-its-square). Can we prove this inequality for general $X$?

Comment: The conjecture  in your question is false. An easy counterexample is the exponential distribution (or indeed, any distribution where the correlation of the mean and the variance is positive / has positive third moment).

Comment: The very form of the statement invites us to contemplate variables with zero expectation, because it implies the covariance of $X$ and $X^2$ must be non-positive in all such cases.  That makes it easy to find counterexamples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it is to proceed from the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353957/covariance-of-a-normal-with-its-square) you linked in comments, at the second last line (at this point no properties of the normal have been used). Note that $Y$ is just a standardized $X$; i.e. $X=\mu+\sigma Y$:

\begin{align}\operatorname{Cov}(X,X^2)&=\sigma^3\operatorname{Cov}(Y,Y^2)+2\mu\sigma^2\operatorname{Cov}(Y,Y)\\
&=\sigma^3\gamma_1+2\mu\sigma^2
\end{align}

where $\gamma_1$ is the moment-skewness. Clearly if the variance and the skewness are strictly positive, $\operatorname{Cov}(X,X^2)$ exceeds $2\mu\sigma^2$

For example, in the case of the standard exponential, $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are both 1, and for any exponential $\gamma_1=2$, so in that case $\operatorname{Cov}(X,X^2)=4$, and each term on the RHS is $2$. A quick simulation confirms that $\operatorname{Cov}(X,X^2)/(\mu\sigma^2)$ is indeed around $4$ for this case (i.e. that ratio is pretty clearly not bounded by 2), so I don't seem to have made any glaring error.

Comment: Thank you. I think picking $X$ and $Y$ the way you did does the job. However, I think that the LHS is $2(\mu + \sigma / \lambda)(\sigma^2 / \lambda^2) = 4$ and not $2\mu\sigma^2 = 2$ since $\mathbb E[X] = \mu + \sigma / \lambda \neq \mu$ and $\mathrm{Var}(X) = \sigma^2 / \lambda^2$. And the RHS $\mathrm{Cov}(X, X^2)$ is $\sigma^3 \mathrm{Cov}(Y, Y^2) + 2\mu\sigma^2 \mathrm{Var}(Y) = 4\sigma^3  / \lambda^3 + 2 \mu\sigma^2 / \lambda^2 = 6$.

Comment: You're mistaken about the meaning of the parameters; $\mu$ here is $E(X)$, $\sigma^2$ is $\text{Var}(X)$, so $\mu=\sigma$ ($=1/\lambda$ if you use the rate parameterization). Note that I chose $\lambda=1$, so $\mu=\sigma=1$.